# How to split expression by comma and space in Java?

Tags: java, regex, split

For instance, source data:

```
some blabla, sentence, example
```

Awaited result:

```
[some,blabla,sentence,example]
```

I can split by comma, but don't know how to split by coma and space at the same time?

My source code, so far:

```
string.split("\\s*,\\s*")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may use a set of chars as separator as described in [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
String string = "One step    at,,a, time ,.";
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( string.split( "[\\s,]+" )));
```

Output:

```
[One, step, at, a, time, .]
```

> \s : A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
>
> [abc] : a, b, or c (simple class)
>
> Greedy quantifiers X+ : X, one or more times

Comment: This helped me save a lot of time. I was using "," as the split delimiter for a string I was reading from a property file. And it always added a space in the resultant array before each element. This helped fix it.

Answer (score 14):

### Solution:

```
String.split("[ ,]+"); // split on on one or more spaces or commas
```

`[]` - simple character class

`[, ]` - simple character class containing space or comma

`[ ,]+` - space or comma showing up one or more times

### Example:

```
String source = "A B    C,,D, E ,F";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(source.split("[, ]+")));
```

Output:

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F]
```